# Dropping out of a Do or For Loop- not working for me

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am attempting to mark rows based on criteria, by putting a value in a column.  In columns a thru f, about 35,000 rows, I have my data. In columns i thru j, only 51 rows, I have my criteria. Column b is empty and I want to fill it with either "KEEP" or "DELETE" based if columns c and f, meet the criteria in columns i and j. Once I hit a "KEEP" value, I want the inner loop to stop and continue with the outer loop. I don't really know exactly what I'm doing (obviously). I would appreciate some help from someone who does.  Thank you!

[image]

```
Sub test()

Dim row As Integer
Dim row2 As Integer
Dim col As Integer
Dim col2 As Integer
Dim col3 As Integer
Dim col4 As Integer
Dim col5 As Integer
Dim x As String
Dim y As String
Dim a As String
Dim b As String

row = 2
row2 = 2
col5 = 2

Do
    col = 3
    col2 = 6
    col3 = 9
    col4 = 10
    x = Cells(row, col).Value
    y = Cells(row, col2).Value
    Z = Cells(row, col5).Value
       For row2 = 2 To 52
            a = Cells(row2, col3).Value
            b = Cells(row2, col4).Value
            If x = a And y = b Then
                Cells(row, col - 1) = "KEEP"
                If (Z = "KEEP") Then Exit For
                Else
                    Cells(row, col - 1) = "DELETE"
            End If
            row2 = row2 + 1
        Next
    row = row + 1
    row2 = 2
Loop Until row >= 33600


End Sub
```

Comment: One way I find very helpful in these issues (loops not working as expected), is to step through it with `F8`.  That will go line by line, and you can even hover the mouse over variables, and a tool-tip will pop up with the evaluated value.  This should help you step through it and find where the macro logic deviates from what you expect.

Comment: Me too Bruce. I really like that technique. I've done it over and over this time too - but I seem to be missing something. Probably because I'm under the gun and feeling a bit stressed. That never helps. :)

Comment: Agreed!  Hm - I recommend taking some time away from the Spreadsheet (if you can :P) then coming back to it fresh.  That's how I spot many errors.  Or of course, there's always [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)!

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
If (Z = "KEEP") Then Exit For
```

to:

```
Exit do
```

EDIT

Put your check in front.

```
For row2 = 2 To 52
     if z = "KEEP" then
        Exit for
     else
        a = Cells(row2, col3).Value
        b = Cells(row2, col4).Value
        If x = a And y = b Then
            Cells(row, col - 1) = "KEEP"
            Exit For
        Else
            Cells(row, col - 1) = "DELETE"
        End If
        row2 = row2 + 1
    end if
Next
```

Comment: Thank you, that's getting closer, but it drops out of the entire routine. I just want to drop to the next loop so it will go to the next row and then go back to the inner loop.

Comment: @KHill Then keep the logic as Scott has it, but instead of saying "If... then Exit For" say "If... z = "KEEP" then [do nothing] Else [All other code]".

Comment: I feel like it's getting so close, but I'm missing something in my counting/looping. It's not giving the correct results. I'm going to try and explain it better. If you look at the snap shot I included at the top - there are almost 36,000 rows of data in the left side of the snap shot in colums A - F. They are invoices that have different months per customer. One customer has many invoices for all the 12 months of the year. In the right side of the snap shot above is a listing of the top 50 customer with a 'Group by Date' in which I've already determined is their highest volume month.

Comment: I simply (or not so simple for me) want to go row-by-row through the data on the left and see if  column C or F match what is in the list on the right. Once I'm identified the "Keep" and the "Delete", I can simply group them and get rid of the deletes. I realize there are many ways to do this - as I've been researching online - and I saw some code around 'filters' but could not seem to follow it. The code above 'seemed' the most straightforward to me - but again, I've got something wrong.  Thanks again to all of you who are looking at this and making suggestions.

Comment: I just realized my example of the snap shot is not good. There is only one customer with one group by date on the right. Not more than one customer with different dates like what I have. My bad!

Answer (score 0):

Because the correct way is :

```
Do Until row >= 33600

'......

Loop
```

With a for

```
for row = 2 to 33600
   '...
                If (Z = "KEEP") Then 
                    Exit For
                Else
                   '...
next row
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's the inner loop I'm having trouble with. The For statement. The bottom line is, the first time it reads through the code it finds a match and puts "KEEP" in the column correctly. But then it continues going through the inner loop and reads the next record, which doesn't match so it changes the "KEEP" to "DELETE".

Comment: When it finds a match and puts "KEEP" write `exit for` which will stop the for loop :)